"Module parse failed: Unexpected token " error after updating to IR compiler
I have updated the Kotlin/Js compiler to IR. I also updated Kotlin's version to 1.9.24 and updated the libraries. Now the project throws an error. What is the error and what needs to be changed, please help.  I searched the whole Internet, but I didn't find anything.What is the error and what needs to be changed, please help.  I searched the whole Internet, but I didn't find anything. And the store is created with the createStore function, note that the last argument of the compose function enables Redux dev tools
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (76474:10)
File was processed with these loaders:

* ../../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |           window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();
  |         else

>           function (f) {

|             return f;
|           };

My code:
package stateManagement

import redux.\*
import stateManagement.layouts.SummaryLayoutState
import stateManagement.layouts.TwoPanelsLayoutState
import stateManagement.layouts.summaryLayoutReducer
import stateManagement.layouts.twoPanelsLayoutReducer
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1

data class State(
val summaryState: SummaryState = SummaryState(),
val watchingState: WatchingState = WatchingState(),
val modelState: ModelState = ModelState(),
val queriesState: QueriesState = QueriesState(),
val serviceState: ServiceState = ServiceState(),
val graphToolsState: GraphToolsState = GraphToolsState(),
val twoPanelsLayoutState: TwoPanelsLayoutState = TwoPanelsLayoutState(),
val summaryLayoutState: SummaryLayoutState = SummaryLayoutState(),
val projectsState: ProjectsState = ProjectsState(),
val notificationsState: NotificationsState = NotificationsState(),
val webSocketState: WebSocketState = WebSocketState(),
val userState: UserState = UserState(),
val documentState: DocumentState = DocumentState(),
val mapState: MapState = MapState(),
val imageState: ImageState = ImageState(),
val dataState: DataState = DataState(),
val submodelState: SubmodelState = SubmodelState(),
val timerState: TimerState = TimerState(),
val mapToolsState: MapToolsState = MapToolsState(),
val timelineState: TimelineState = TimelineState(),
val reportsState: ReportsState = ReportsState(),
val voiceAssistantState: VoiceAssistantState = VoiceAssistantState(),
val decisionTreeState: DecisionTreeState = DecisionTreeState(),
val patternState: PatternState = PatternState(),
val statisticState: StatisticState = StatisticState()
)

fun \<S, A, R\> combineReducers(reducers: Map\<KProperty1\<S, R\>, Reducer\<\*, A\>\>): Reducer\<S, A\> {
return redux.combineReducers(reducers.mapKeys { it.key.name })
}

fun reducers() = combineReducers(
mapOf(
State::summaryState to ::summaryReducer,
State::watchingState to ::watchingReducer,
State::modelState to ::modelReducer,
State::queriesState to ::queriesReducer,
State::serviceState to ::serviceReducer,
State::graphToolsState to ::graphToolsReducer,
State::twoPanelsLayoutState to ::twoPanelsLayoutReducer,
State::summaryLayoutState to ::summaryLayoutReducer,
State::projectsState to ::projectsReducer,
State::notificationsState to ::notificationsReducer,
State::userState to ::userReducer,
State::documentState to ::documentReducer,
State::webSocketState to ::webSocketReducer,
State::mapState to ::mapReducer,
State::imageState to ::imageReducer,
State::dataState to ::dataReducer,
State::submodelState to ::submodelReducer,
State::mapToolsState to ::mapToolsReducer,
State::timerState to ::timerReducer,
State::timelineState to ::timelineReducer,
State::reportsState to ::reportsReducer,
State::voiceAssistantState to ::voiceAssistantReducer,
State::decisionTreeState to ::decisionTreeReducer,
State::patternState to ::patternReducer,
State::statisticState to ::statisticReducer
)
)

val store = createStore(
reducers(), State(), compose(
rThunk(),
rEnhancer(),
js("if(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ )window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ();else(function(f){return f;});") as Function1\<Function2\<Function2\<State, Action, State\>, State, Store\<State, Action, Action\>\>, Function2\<Function2\<State, Action, State\>, State, Store\<State, Action, Action\>\>\>
)
)


